# Most elegant and fastest way to remove all leading zeroes in perl string

Tags: regex, string, perl, substring

I wrote `rmlz` function for trimming all leading zeroes from string.

```
# remove all leading zeroes from string
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

sub rmlz {
  my ( $str ) = @_;
  if ( $str =~ /^(.[0])/ ) {
    return substr( $str, length($1));
  }
  return $str;
}

say rmlz('0050625'); # must return 50625
```

Is there most elegant and clear way to rewrite this code ? Or regexp+length+substr is best option ?

Comment: Do you care about the actual amount?

Comment: @DaveSherohman, yeah, I need to remove. Thanks for question, I updated title.

Comment: yes, exactly! fixed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple substitution will remove leading zeros:

```
$str =~ s/^0+(?=[0-9])//;
```

This removes as many zeros as possible while still leaving at least one digit.
The latter constraint is needed to prevent "0" becoming "".

Answer (score 4):

Since this seems to be about a number, can reformat it as such (if indeed an integer)

```
my $num = sprintf "%d", $num_in_str;
```

or have Perl take care of it by making it treat the string as a number

```
my $num = 0 + $num_in_str;   # or just:  $num_in_str += 0;
```

This does the right thing for any kind of number in `$num_in_str`, and it is incomparably more efficient than `sprintf` or starting a regex engine.  While it may appear tricky it's fine in a sub

```
sub rmlz { return 0+$_[0] }
```

where you practically pay only for the function call overhead (still a bit in Perl).

Both of these print warnings if `$num_in_str` isn't a valid number, what is good in my opinion (unless you need to work with things like `0023a`, in which case you want a regex).

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitute operator

```
$str =~ s/^0+//
```

Replace the beginning of the string followed by 1 or more `0` with nothing instead of

```
if ( $str =~ /^(.[0])/ ) {
    return substr( $str, length($1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$_+=0;

this problem is more easily solved by math than regex